# JavaScript to update active sidebar menuSubItems linked to TabPanel in dashboard

Tags: javascript, shiny, shinydashboard, sidebar, shinyjs

I am trying to build a Shiny dashboard with menuSubItems that should correspond to TabPanels. I need also a button on the Home page that move to these TabPanels. This part is not working too bad. The issues come when I try to use some JavaScript code to update which are the 'active' items in the sidebar (reproducible example below).

My main issues are the following:

1. I am not able to set as 'active' the correct menuSubItem in the sidebar : in the js console, I see that the `<li>` items are correctly selected, but for an unknown reason `classList.add('active');` (or `remove`) remain ineffective.
2. When I switch from "Tabpan" menuSubItems to Home or Settings, I would like the "Tab1" menuItem to collapse; here again, I've tried to do it with js (update class to `style.display = 'none';`) ; sometimes it works, sometimes it does not (it would be easier to understand if it was always working or not working ...).
3. There are kind of 'stochastic' behaviors that I don't understand. The Tabpan1 and Tabpan2 (and their corresponding `observeEvent`) are constructed exactly in the same way (using `lapply`), but Tabpan2 seems to work better than Tabpan1. Also, sometimes switching from Tabpanel TabPan1 to Settings works - sometimes it does not.

How can I debug the following app?

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
require(shinydashboard)
require(shinydashboardPlus)
mymenu <- list(list(menuitem=c("Tab1" = "tab1"),
                    subitems=c("Tabpan1" = "tsp1_tabpan1", "Tapan2"="tsp1_tabpan2"),
                    icon="upload"))
build_menu <- function(list_item){
  lapply(list_item, function(x){
    subs <- x[["subitems"]]
    men <- x[["menuitem"]]
    menusubits <- lapply(seq_along(subs), function(i){
      HTML(paste0('<li><a id="mv_',men,'_',subs[i] , '" href="#shiny-tab-',men ,'" class="action-button" data-value="',men,'">
<i class="fas fa-angles-right" role="presentation" aria-label="angles-right icon"></i> ', names(subs)[i],'</a></li>'))
    })
    menuItem(names(men), id=as.character(men), icon = icon(x[["icon"]]),menusubits)
  })
}
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="sidebar",
                menuItem("Accueil",tabName = "home", icon = icon("igloo")),
                build_menu(mymenu),
                menuItem("Réglages", tabName = "settings", icon = icon("gears"))
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "home",
              h1("Home"),
              HTML('<br><br><ul><li><a id="see_tab1_pan1" class="action-button" >
                                  Go to tab1 pan1</a></li><br><br>
                                  <li><a id="see_tab1_pan2" class="action-button" >
                                  Go to tab1 pan2</a></li>'),),
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
              h1("Tab1"),
              tabsetPanel(id="tab1_tabset",
              tabPanel("TabPan1", value=paste0("tab1_tsp1_tabpan1"),
                       h4("tp tit1")
              ),
            tabPanel("TabPan2", value=paste0("tab1_tsp1_tabpan2"),
                     h4("tp tit2")
            ),)),
      tabItem(tabName = "settings",
              h1("Settings")
    ))))


  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$see_tab1_pan1,{
      cat(paste0("click_test\n"))
      # debug see_tab1_pan2 first :-)
    })
    observeEvent(input$see_tab1_pan2,{
      cat(paste0("click_test\n"))
      runjs(paste0(
        # emulate a click on menusubitem :
        "var x = document.getElementById('", "mv_tab1_tsp1_tabpan2", "'); ",
        "console.log(x);",
        "x.click();",
        # "// leaving Home -> remove active class ",
        "const $parent = $('.sidebar-menu [data-value=\"home\"]').closest('li');",
        "console.log('parent');",
        "console.log($parent);",
        "$parent.removeClass('active');",
        #"// expand the correspondign menuitem
        "var y = document.getElementById('", "tab1", "'); ",
        "console.log('y');",
        "console.log(y);",
        "y.style.display = 'block';",
        "y.classList.add('menu-open');"#,
    ))})
    ### collapse menuitems if I am in home or settings
    observe({
      if(input$sidebar == "home" | input$sidebar == "settings"){
        #"// collapse the tab1 menuitem
        runjs(paste0("var y = document.getElementById('", "tab1", "'); ",
        "console.log('y');",
        "console.log(y);",
        "y.style.display = 'none';",
        "y.classList.remove('menu-open');"#,
        ))
      }
    })

    lapply(mymenu, function(x){
      men <- as.character(x[["menuitem"]])
      stopifnot(length(men) == 1)
      subits <- x[["subitems"]]
      lapply(seq_along(subits), function(i){
        btnid <- paste0("mv_", men, "_", subits[i])
        observeEvent(input[[btnid]],{
         cat( paste0("click ",btnid,"\n") )
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = men)
          updateTabItems(session, inputId = paste0(men, "_tabset"),
                         selected = paste0(men, "_", subits[i]))
          runjs(paste0(
      #"// find all other <li> elements of the menuitem and remove active class",
        "var btn = document.getElementById('", btnid, "');",
        "console.log('btn');",
        "console.log(btn);",
               "var allLi = btn.closest('ul').getElementsByTagName('li');",
               " for (var i = 0; i < allLi.length; i++) {",
        "console.log('allLi[i] - BEFORE');",
        "console.log(allLi[i]);",
                 " allLi[i].classList.remove('active');", #### NOT WORKING ????
        "console.log('allLi[i] - AFTER');",
        "console.log(allLi[i]);",
                 "}" ,
      # "// add 'active' class to <li> of the corresponding menusubitem button ",
      "var z = btn.closest('li');",
      "console.log('will add active to');",
      "console.log(z);",
      "  z.classList.add('active');",
      "  console.log('after set active class');", #### NOT WORKING ????
      "console.log(z);"
      ))
        }
      )})})}

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following workaround, but I find it not clean at all and am still waiting a better answer...

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
require(shinydashboard)
require(shinydashboardPlus)


mymenu <- list(list(menuitem=c("Tab1" = "tab1"),
                    subitems=c("Tabpan1" = "tsp1_tabpan1", "Tabpan2"="tsp1_tabpan2"),
                    menuIcon="upload",
                    subMenuIcon = "angles-right"))

getMenuSubmenuItems <- function(list_item){
  lapply(list_item, function(x){
    subs <- x[["subitems"]]
    men <- x[["menuitem"]]
    menusubits <- lapply(seq_along(subs), function(i){
      HTML(paste0('<li><a id="mv_',men,'_',subs[i] , '" href="#shiny-tab-',men ,'" class="action-button" data-value="',men,'">
<i class="fas fa-', x[["subMenuIcon"]], '" role="presentation" aria-label="',x[["subMenuIcon"]] ,' icon"></i> ', 
                  names(subs)[i],'</a></li>'))
    })
    list( HTML(paste0('<li class="treeview">
          <a href="#" id="', as.character(men) ,'_parent" class="action-button">
        <i class="fas fa-', x[["menuIcon"]],'" role="presentation" aria-label="', x[["menuIcon"]],' icon"></i>
        <span>', names(men), '</span>
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left pull-right" role="presentation" aria-label="angle-left icon"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;" data-expanded="', names(men),'" id="', as.character(men),'">')),
      menusubits,
      HTML("</ul></li>"))})}

generate_home_menu <-function(mymenu){
  lapply(mymenu, function(menuit){
    mi <- menuit[["menuitem"]]
    si <- menuit[["subitems"]]
    start <- paste0("<h4>", names(mi), "</h4><ul>")
    its <- paste0(sapply(seq_along(si), function(i){
      paste0('<li><a id="see_', as.character(si[i]), '" class="action-button" >
                    Go to ', names(si)[i], '</a></li><br>')
    }), collapse="")
    end <- paste0("</ul>")
    HTML(paste0(c(start, its, end), collapse=""))})}  
generate_subitem_panels <- function(mymenu){
  lapply(mymenu, function(x){
    mi <- x[["menuitem"]]
    si <- x[["subitems"]]
    tabItem(tabName = as.character(mi),
            h1(names(mi)),
            tabsetPanel(id=paste0(mi, "_tabset"),
                        ### iterate over menuSubItems to create corresponding tabPanels
                        !!!lapply(seq_along(si), function(i){
                          tabPanel(names(si)[i], value = paste0(mi, "_", si[i]),
                                   h4(names(si[i])))})))})}

getMenuItem <- function(id, label, icon){
  return(HTML(paste0('<li><a href="#shiny-tab-', id, '" id="', id , '_btn" data-toggle="tab" class="action-button"
              data-value="', id, '">
                <i class="fas fa-', icon, '" role="presentation" aria-label="', icon, ' icon"></i>
                <span>', label, '</span>
              </a></li>')))}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="sidebar",
                getMenuItem("home", "Accueil", "igloo"),
                getMenuSubmenuItems(mymenu),
            getMenuItem("settings", "Settings", "gears"))),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
      do.call(tabItems,c(list(
        tabItem(tabName = "home", ## tabName should match id used in getMenuItem !!
                h1("Home"),
                generate_home_menu(mymenu)
        )),
      generate_subitem_panels(mymenu),
      list(tabItem(tabName = "settings", ## tabName should match id used in getMenuItem !!
              h1("Settings")))))))
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    lapply(mymenu, function(mi){
      mit <- as.character(mi[["menuitem"]])
      si <- mi[["subitems"]]
      lapply(si, function(subi){
        observeEvent(input[[paste0("see_", subi)]],{
          runjs(paste0(
            "var x = document.getElementById('", paste0(mit,"_parent"), "'); 
            x.click();"))
          Sys.sleep(1)
          runjs(paste0(
            "var x = document.getElementById('", paste0("mv_", mit, "_", subi), "');
            x.click();"))})})} )
   
    lapply(c("home", "settings"), function(tab){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0(tab, "_btn")]], {
        runjs(paste0("console.log('clicked ", tab, "');
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul.sidebar-menu ul.treeview-menu.menu-open');
console.log(elements);
elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.remove('menu-open');
    element.style.display = 'none';});"))})})

    lapply(mymenu, function(m){
      mi <- as.character(m[["menuitem"]])
      msi <- m[["subitems"]]
      lapply(msi, function(it){
        observeEvent(input[[paste0(mi, "_tabset")]],{
          if(input[[paste0(mi, "_tabset")]] == paste0(mi, "_", it)){
            btnid <- paste0("mv_", mi, "_", it)
            runjs(paste0(
              "var btn = document.getElementById('", btnid, "');",
              "var allLi = btn.closest('ul').getElementsByTagName('li');
              for (var i = 0; i < allLi.length; i++) {
              if(allLi[i].querySelector('a').id == '",btnid, "'){",
              "allLi[i].querySelector('a').dataset.value='", mi, "';",
              "} else{",
              "allLi[i].querySelector('a').dataset.value='",mi, "_foo';",
              "}
              allLi[i].classList.remove('active');
              }
              var z = btn.closest('li');
                z.classList.add('active');"
            ))}})})}) 

    lapply(mymenu, function(x){
      men <- as.character(x[["menuitem"]])
      stopifnot(length(men) == 1)
      subits <- x[["subitems"]]
      lapply(seq_along(subits), function(i){
        btnid <- paste0("mv_", men, "_", subits[i])
        observeEvent(input[[btnid]],{
          updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", selected = men)
          updateTabItems(session, inputId = paste0(men, "_tabset"),
                         selected = paste0(men, "_", subits[i]))
        })})})}
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and I am still struggling with this part specifically :

```
          runjs(paste0(
            "var x = document.getElementById('", paste0(mit,"_parent"), "'); 
            x.click();"))
          Sys.sleep(1)
          runjs(paste0(
            "var x = document.getElementById('", paste0("mv_", mit, "_", subi), "');
            x.click();"))
```

(posted in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77748584/javascript-in-r-shiny-app-wait-busy-ui-before-continuing))

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35475571)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine you voted to delete this?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine not sure to understand your comment, isn't it exactly what I did by indicating "(posted in this other SO question)" ?